# Magento Ajax Cart

Tags: magento

estou tendo um problema no magento.. com o carrinho em ajax.. quando eu adiciono ou removo um produto no carrinho.. o produto é adicionado e também excluido.. porém.. ele não aparece quando adiciono.. e nem some quando excluo... só com reload da pagina.. mas não aparece nenhum erro no console.. nem nos arquivos de log.. aparentemente ta tudo certo.. a única coisa que acontece que ele retorna com sucesso.. mas não exibe o produto no carrinho.. nada.. só quando faço reload na page... nem exclui quando é o caso.

alguém pode me da uma luz ?

quando remove.

```
{message: "Item was removed.", r: "success"}
message
:
"Item was removed."
r
:
"success"
```

quando adiciono

```
{product_name: "Camiseta Fitness Don't Stop At Good Ref: 10094",…}
message
:
"Camiseta Fitness Don't Stop At Good Ref: 10094 was added into cart."
product_name
:
"Camiseta Fitness Don't Stop At Good Ref: 10094"
r
:
"success"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eu uso esse módulo para adicionar os itens ao meu carrinho**

Baixe o jQuery [Aqui](http://jquery.com/download/)

Salve com o nome **jquery.js** em **magento/js/jquery**

Crie um arquivo chamado **noconflict.js** em **/magento/js/jquery** e coloque isto dentro: **jQuery.noConflict();** e salve o arquivo

Agora vamos criar o nosso módulo

Crie as respectivas pastas **magento/app/code/local/{suaempresa}/Ajax**
Dentro delas crie mais duas pastas uma chamada **etc** e **controllers**

Dentro de **etc** crie o arquivo lembre de substituir o campo Suaempresa 
**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Suaempresa_Ajax>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Suaempresa_Ajax>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <ajax>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Suaempresa_Ajax</module>
                    <frontName>ajax</frontName>
                </args>
            </ajax>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <ajax>
                    <file>ajax.xml</file>
                </ajax>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>   
    <global>
        <resources>
            <ajax_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Suaempresa_Ajax</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </ajax_setup>
            <ajax_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </ajax_write>
            <ajax_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </ajax_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <ajax_cart> <!--This can be any unique id -->
                <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>  <!-- the URL which u want to override-->
                <to>/ajax/index/</to>  <!-- destination url -->
            </ajax_cart>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

Dentro de **controllers** crie 
**IndexController.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Floresonline_Ajax_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {

public function addAction()
    {
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if($params['isAjax'] == 1){
            $response = array();
            try {
                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                    );
                    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                }

                $product = $this->_initProduct();
                $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to find Product ID');
                }

                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                if (!empty($related)) {
                    $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
                }

                $cart->save();

                $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

                /**
                 * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
                 */
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
                );

                if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                    if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                        $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                        $response['status'] = 'O item foi adicionado com sucesso';
                        $response['message'] = $message;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if ($url) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            } else {
                $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
            }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
            return;
        }else{
            return parent::addAction();
        }
    }

    public function optionsAction(){
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
        // Prepare helper and params
        $viewHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');

        $params = new Varien_Object();
        $params->setCategoryId(false);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions(false);

        // Render page
        try {
            $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
                if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                    $this->_redirect('');
                } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                    $this->_forward('noRoute');
                }
            } else {
                Mage::logException($e);
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getWishlist($wishlistId = null)
    {
        $wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
        if ($wishlist) {
            return $wishlist;
        }
        try {
            if (!$wishlistId) {
                $wishlistId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('wishlist_id');
            }
            $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
            $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');

            if ($wishlistId) {
                $wishlist->load($wishlistId);
            } else {
                $wishlist->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
            }

            if (!$wishlist->getId() || $wishlist->getCustomerId() != $customerId) {
                $wishlist = null;
                Mage::throwException(
                    Mage::helper('wishlist')->__("Requested wishlist doesn't exist")
                );
            }

            Mage::register('wishlist', $wishlist);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addException($e,
            Mage::helper('wishlist')->__('Cannot create wishlist.')
            );
            return false;
        }

        return $wishlist;
    }
    public function addwishAction()
    {

        $response = array();
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('wishlist/general/active')) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Wishlist Has Been Disabled By Admin');
        }
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Please Login First');
        }

        if(empty($response)){
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
            if (!$wishlist) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to Create Wishlist');
            }else{

                $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
                if (!$productId) {
                    $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Product Not Found');
                }else{

                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                    if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                        $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot specify product.');
                    }else{

                        try {
                            $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                            if ($session->getBeforeWishlistRequest()) {
                                $requestParams = $session->getBeforeWishlistRequest();
                                $session->unsBeforeWishlistRequest();
                            }
                            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($requestParams);

                            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
                            if (is_string($result)) {
                                Mage::throwException($result);
                            }
                            $wishlist->save();

                            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                                'wishlist_add_product',
                            array(
                                'wishlist'  => $wishlist,
                                'product'   => $product,
                                'item'      => $result
                            )
                            );


                            $referer = $session->getBeforeWishlistUrl();
                            if ($referer) {
                                $session->setBeforeWishlistUrl(null);
                            } else {
                                $referer = $this->_getRefererUrl();
                            }
                            $session->setAddActionReferer($referer);

                            Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

                            $message = $this->__('%1$s has been added to your wishlist.',
                            $product->getName(), Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($referer));

                            $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                            $response['message'] = $message;

                            Mage::unregister('wishlist');

                            $this->loadLayout();
                            $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                            $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('wishlist_sidebar');
                            $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                            $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                            $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                        }
                        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                            $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage());
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e) {
                            mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                            $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }
    public function compareAction(){
        $response = array();

        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

        if ($productId && (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);

            if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
                $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('The product %s has been added to comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
                $this->loadLayout();
                $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.compare.sidebar');
                $sidebar_block->setTemplate('ajaxwishlist/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml');
                $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }
}
```

Crie um arquivo chamado **ajaxwishlist.js** em **magento/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/ajaxwishlist**
**ajaxwishlist.js**

```
function ajaxCompare(url,id){
    url = url.replace("catalog/product_compare/add","ajax/index/compare");
    url += 'isAjax/1/';
    jQuery('#ajax_loading'+id).show();
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            jQuery('#ajax_loading'+id).hide();
            if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                alert(data.message);
            }else{
                alert(data.message);
                if(jQuery('.block-compare').length){
                    jQuery('.block-compare').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                }else{
                    if(jQuery('.col-right').length){
                        jQuery('.col-right').prepend(data.sidebar);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
function ajaxWishlist(url,id){
    url = url.replace("wishlist/index/add","ajax/index/addwish");
    url += 'isAjax/1/';
    jQuery('#ajax_loading'+id).show();
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            jQuery('#ajax_loading'+id).hide();
            if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                alert(data.message);
            }else{
                alert(data.message);
                if(jQuery('.block-wishlist').length){
                    jQuery('.block-wishlist').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                }else{
                    if(jQuery('.col-right').length){
                        jQuery('.col-right').prepend(data.sidebar);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Crie um arquivo chamado **ajax.xml** em 
 **app/design/frontend/{seutema}/default/layout/**

**ajax.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/noconflict.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ajaxwishlist/ajaxwishlist.js</name></action> 
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js</name></action>  
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name='product.info'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <template>ajax/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name='product.info.addtocart'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <template>ajax/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name='product.info.addto'>
            <action method='setTemplate'><template>ajax/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/noconflict.js</name></action>  
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ajaxwishlist/ajaxwishlist.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js</name></action>  
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name='product_list'>
            <action method='setTemplate'><template>ajax/catalog/product/list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/noconflict.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ajaxwishlist/ajaxwishlist.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name='product_list'>
            <action method='setTemplate'><template>ajax/catalog/product/list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <ajax_index_options>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/noconflict.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="ajax/catalog/product/options.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="ajax/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </ajax_index_options>
</layout>
```

Adicione em **app/design/frontend/{seutema}/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        var form = this.form;
                        var oldUrl = form.action;

                        if (url) {
                           form.action = url;
                        }
                        var e = null;
        //Start of our new ajax code
                        if(!url){
                        url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
                        }
                        url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index"); 
                        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                        data += '&isAjax=1';   
                        jQuery('#ajax_loader').show();
                        try {
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                  url: url,
                                  dataType: 'json',
                                  type : 'post',
                                  data: data,
                                  success: function(data){
                                        jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                                        //alert(data.status + ": " + data.message);
                                        if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
                                            jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                                        }
                                        if(jQuery('.header .links')){
                                            jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                                            window.location.href = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("checkout/cart");?>';
                                        }
                                  }
                            });
                        } catch (e) {
                        }

        //End of our new ajax code
                        this.form.action = oldUrl;
                        if (e) {
                            throw e;
                        }

                        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                            button.disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Comment: Fala aê meu brother.. tranquilo?! então mano eu já resolvi o problema.. mas te dei uma moral ai de qualquer maneira por ter perdido um pouco do seu tempo pra tentar me ajudar! o problema estava em uma configuração de modulo que eu não estava vendo mano.. precisava inserir algumas informações lá e voilá.. tudo funcionando novamente! sucesso brother.

Comment: Tranquilo! Sem problemas, qualquer coisa que precisar tamo aê! Abraços, sucesso!